# Implementing a Service with BroadCastReceiver

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcast, android-handler

I have a `BroadCastRecevier` that works in an asnyc task and it works when server sent a message then broadcast sends this server messages to activities. When activity get the message I am doing some process using a `Handler` However sometimes handler is not triggered. I mean broadcast sends three messages but handler works two times.

```
g.broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        srvrMessage = intent.getStringExtra("message");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(50);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        myHandler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
    }
};
```

To avoid this issue I decide to use a `Service`. I have created a service class and want that handler work inside of it but I could not send myHandler as a parameter while starting the service. How can I make this handler works in the service?

Comment: I will suggest you to move your handler inside onStartCommand() of service

Answer (score 0):

I think these links will help you:- 
http://techblogon.com/android-service-example-code-description-complete-tutorial/
http://blog.denevell.org/android-service-handler-tutorial.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will examine these links.